# Trying to stub a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to stub a function that returns a promise but it doesn't work... I'm using Node.js, Mocha, Chai and Sinon.

```
// index.js
const toStub = () => {
  return Promise.resolve('foo');
};

const toTest = () => {
  return toStub()
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(`THEN: ${r}`);
      return 42;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(`CATCH: ${e}`);
      throw 21;
    });
};

module.exports = { toStub, toTest };
```

With this test implementation:

```
// index.spec.js
let chai = require('chai')
  , should = chai.should();

let sinon = require('sinon');

let { toStub, toTest } = require('../src/index');

describe('test the toTest function', () => {
  it('should be rejected', (done) => {
    toStub = sinon.stub().rejects('foofoo'); // <---------- here
    toTest()
      .then(r => {
        console.log(`THEN_2 ${r}`);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(`CATCH_2 ${e}`);
      });
      done();
  });
});
```

This is what I get when I run this unit test:

```
$ npm t
  test the toTest function
    ✓ should be rejected
THEN: foo
THEN_2 42
```

It should print this out below instead:

```
$ npm t
  test the toTest function
    ✓ should be rejected
CATCH: foofoo
CATCH_2 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to make it work.

```
// tostub.js       
function toStub() {
   return Promise.resolve('foo');
}
module.exports = toStub
```

Your index.js becomes:

```
const toStub = require('./tostub')
const toTest = () => {
  return toStub()
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(`THEN: ${r}`);
      return 42;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(`CATCH: ${e}`);
      throw 21;
    });
};
module.exports = toTest;
```

Finally, the key thing in your test is to use "[mock-require](https://github.com/boblauer/mock-require)" module

```
// index.spec.js
const mock = require('mock-require');
let chai = require('chai')
  , should = chai.should();

let sinon = require('sinon');
mock('../src/tostub', sinon.stub().rejects('foofoo'))
let toTest = require('../src/index');

describe('test the toTest function', () => {
  it('should be rejected', (done) => {
    toTest()
      .then(r => {
        console.log(`THEN_2 ${r}`);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(`CATCH_2 ${e}`);
      });
      done();
  });
});
```

By running npm test, you should get:

```
→ npm test

> stub@1.0.0 test /Users/kevin/Desktop/main/tmp/stub
> mocha



  test the toTest function
    ✓ should be rejected
CATCH: foofoo
CATCH_2 21


  1 passing (12ms)
```